# Derived Column condition to get string between two Hyphens

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need an SSIS expression to get the left part of a string before the separator, and then put the new string in a new column. I checked in derived column, it seems no such expressions. "Substring" could only return string part with fixed length.  For example, with separator string '-' :

input : `MQ-240030-Black`
expected output : `240030`

my attempt :

```
SUBSTRING(name,1,FINDSTRING(name,"-",1) - 1)
```

Comment: post some more input string

Comment: what if we want BLACK As O/P from input : MQ-240030-Black

Comment: Try .. Select upper(right(@a,5)) to get black..-- BLACK

Answer (score 0):

Change the Expression to
`SUBSTRING(name,FINDSTRING(name,"-",1) + 1,FINDSTRING(name,"-",2) - FINDSTRING(name,"-",1) - 1)`

**EDITED**

substring `name` from the index after the first occurrence of hyphen (`FINDSTRING(name,"-",1) + 1`) to the index before the second occurrence of hyphen (`FINDSTRING(name,"-",2) - FINDSTRING(name,"-",1) - 1`)

**EDITED AGAIN**

To get "BLACK" as output

substring `name` from the index after the second occurrence of hyphen (`FINDSTRING(name,"-",2) + 1`) to the last index (`LEN(name)`) So, it will be

```
UPPER(SUBSTRING(name,FINDSTRING(name,"-",2) + 1,LEN(name)))
```

I included `UPPER()` as I see the result string in Upper cases.

Comment: substring `name` from the index after the first occurrence of hyphen (`FINDSTRING(name,"-",1) + 1`) to the index before the second occurrence of hyphen (`FINDSTRING(name,"-",2) - FINDSTRING(name,"-",1) - 1`)

Comment: Now edit this into your answer and everything's fine ;)

Comment: what if we want BLACK As O/P from input : MQ-240030-Black

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
SUBSTRING(name,FINDSTRING(name,"-",1) + 1,FINDSTRING(name,"-",2) - FINDSTRING(name,"-",1) - 1)
```

Result:

```
name            name2
MQ-240030-Black 240030
```

Answer (score 0):

All what you need to use is the following Syntax:

```
  FINDSTRING(@[namespace::input], "-", 2) != 0 ?TOKEN( @[namespace::input], "-" , 2) : "ERR_INPUT"
```